# Difficult query for calculating user appeared certain days before

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table

```
id, date
a , 2017-01-01
a , 2017-01-02
b , 2017-02-03
...
```

and I'd like to compute for each day D, how many distinct user appeared exactly 7 days ago (on that day), but not in-between D-7 and D. Don't care about if they appear before day D

And the output shall be

```
date, count
2017-01-01, 23
2017-01-02, 33
```

etc

I've been thinking about this for quite a while, but can't figure out the D to D+7 part out. Easily converted into python, but I'd like to sharpen my SQL skills :) 
I know basic select, group by clauses, but I'm just wondering if there're any advanced techniques I should know about.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It wouldn't be D+7 if you want the date from 7 days ago. For example, you would subtract 7 days. SELECT DATE_SUB('2017-01-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY); I don't know what your user table schema looks like you should probably share that

Comment: @atomCode Edited. Sorry it should be D-7 to D.

Comment: it's exactly two columns. id is user's Id, unique, and date is the date that user appeared that day

Comment: If id column is unique why do you have 2 "a" in your example??

Comment: Try thinking of them as sets. You're looking for the difference between the set of people who appeared a day and the set of people who appeared during the next 7 days. First build the two underlying sets (which is pretty basic) and then apply a difference operator (usually "not in") to get your results. You can aggregate it afterwards.

Comment: @dragmosh Thanks for the tip! Indeed was thinking about that. I started simple with just one day (like 2017-08-07) and tried to combine two sets (users didn't show up from 2017-08-02 to 2017-08-07, intersect with people showed up on 2017-08-01) and then got stuck there

Comment: The result set does not match the data set. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The basic query is `select id from ztable t.where t.zdate=today and exists(select 1 from ztable x where x.id=t.id AND x.zdate =t.zdate-7days) AND not exists( select1 from ztable nx where nx.id=t.id AND nx.zdate = daterange_inbetween);`, and:add the aggregation as @dragmosh commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user appeared on that day and 7 days ago

```
SELECT DDate,
       COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM tablename a
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                FROM tablename
               WHERE DDate = DATE_SUB(a.DDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
             )
 GROUP BY DDate
```

Comment: `WHERE id EXISTS`? Maybe you mean `WHERE id IN (...)`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of WHERE EXISTS and WHERE id IN. It got mixed up.

Comment: But this doesn't ensure the user didn't appear from D-7 to D, right?

Comment: this checks the users who appeared on a particular day and has appeared as well exactly 7 days ago

Comment: Let's say user 'a' appeared on Jan 1 2017 (2017-01-01) and Dec 25 2016 (2016-12-25), which is 7 days ago, it will count. But if it appeared also any day on Dec 26 2016 to Dec 31 2016 (2016-12-26/2016-25-31), you didn't want that user to be counted, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to help you with the assumption of what I understand about your question

just from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
select count(date), date from tablename where date<=CURDATE() + interval 7 day group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join on the same table for the 7 days in the future to see if the ID shows up. If it doesn't show up, the left joined table's id will be null.

```
select count(distinct t1.id), t1.date + interval 7 day
from table t1
left join table t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.date < t1.date + interval 7 day and t2.date >= t1.date
where t2.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ferdinand Gasper's answer, but this excludes the users who appeared less than 7 days before:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM yourTable AS t1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
            FROM yourTable AS t2
            WHERE t2.date = DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id
            FROM yourTable AS t2
            WHERE t2.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Looks like your conditions are excluding, because the first subquery returns a subset of the second.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The second one should have used `INTERVAL 6 DAY`, fixed it.